# Match key/values within unique ID range to a different matching key

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Shopify recently added a feature to allow product images to be associated with product variants. They updated their product import/export feature with a new column that allows you to associate image URLs with specific variants.

Here is an abstracted simplified look:

```
handle      option  img url     img atl   option img url
---------------------------------------------------------------------
unique-1    blue    URLblue1    blue      wanted value: URLblue1
unique-1    blue    URLred1     red       wanted value: URLblue1
unique-1    red     URLgreen1   green     wanted value: URLred1 
unique-1    red                           wanted value: URLred1
unique-1    green                         wanted value: URLgreen1
unique-1    green                         wanted value: URLgreen1
unique-2    blue    URLblue2    blue      wanted value: URLblue2
unique-2    blue    URLred2     red       wanted value: URLblue2
unique-2    red     URLgreen2   green     wanted value: URLred2
unique-2    red                           wanted value: URLred2
unique-2    green                         wanted value: URLgreen2
unique-2    green                         wanted value: URLgreen2
```

where I've written 'wanted value' is where there will be a blank column on the spreadsheet. I am looking for some kind of formula I could put in that column to come up with the wanted value.

Comment: Does the solution have to work in MS Excel, or Google Sheets, or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only work in Google Sheets, and should be placed in E2, assuming your first wanted value is in E2:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(C1,C:C,VLOOKUP(A2:A,QUERY({A2:D,ROW(A2:A)},"select Col1, min(Col5) where Col4 != '' group by Col1 pivot Col4"),MATCH(B2:B,SORT(UNIQUE(D2:D)),0)+1,0),0)))`

It also assumes that I have interpreted your abstraction correctly, so please report back if it fails on your actual data.

Comment: it didn't work. here is a link to readable spreadsheet with more specific data. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tgXbxTf_RSbONcC9CH3bJ1dD2sPhgpiCP4yumtjmmzw/edit?usp=sharing        i changed it so that the column E is now column C, next to the column B which the urls should ultimately be lined up next two. The handle range (column A) basically defines each product, and the image url and image alt are sort of idependant from actual rows, just as long as their values are contained in a row with the product handle (column A)

Comment: For that layout, try `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(D1,D:D,VLOOKUP(A2:A,QUERY({A2:A,D2:E,ROW(A2:A)},"select Col1, min(Col4) where Col3 != '' group by Col1 pivot Col3"),MATCH(B2:B,SORT(UNIQUE(E2:E)),0)+1,0),0)))`

Comment: where does that formula get placed?

Comment: It is to be entered in C2.

Comment: I used the old formula in the context of the sheet link I posted, and the values are displaced following a pattern I can't decipher. http://imgur.com/A0sXCWm

Comment: the way you adapted the formula caused an error for some reason. So I just used the original column layout with the old formula, and it seemed to come somewhat close but with some expected behavoir.

Comment: Would you be able to use whatever layout suits you best, and I will give the solution. Preferably if you could (temporarily) allow me to edit the ss.

Comment: Here is a copy of your ss, with both layout options: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GR8kQi-BEYSLvvjXFbIpJX-Y1zZX4aRpB3nlxNoRMyE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I think part of the issue is when formulae are copy and pasted, the double-quotation marks often get changed to non-supported characters. I had to go in and manually replace the double-quotation marks to get it to work.

Comment: Its working great. I just ran a test on a new sheet. Awesome!

Comment: here is the final formula:     =ArrayFormula(HLOOKUP(D1,D:D,VLOOKUP(A2:A,QUERY({A2:A,D2:E,ROW(A2:A)},"select Col1, min(Col4) where Col3 != '' group by Col1 pivot Col3"),MATCH(B2:B,SORT(UNIQUE(E2:E)),0)+1,0),0))